# argparse - Reproduce behavior of "--help" argument with a specific argument

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, argparse

I have some trouble while working with the `argparse` module for Python v2.7.
Basically, what I have is a script that works with 5 mandatory arguments :

1. url
2. method
3. login
4. password
5. output

An example of the syntax would look like this :

> script.py -w/--url [URL] -m/--method [METHOD] -l/--login [LOGIN] -p/--password [PASSWORD] -o/--output [OUTPUT]

What I'd like to do is this :

- add an optional argument `-t/--test`
- its behavior would be that, based on the url used with the `-w/--url` argument, it would bypass completely the `-m/--method`, `-l/--login` and `-p/--password` arguments but, for it to work, I need to tell `argparse` to stop processing arguments if `-t/--test` is provided (but only with `-w/--url`).

Is this behavior even possible? I tried to play with `argparse` sub-commands but it seems to be (at least to my small knowledge) a bit overkill.

*NB: Here is my original code :*

```
# Description : parses script arguments
# Argument(s) : all
# Return value : all arguments values
def testArgs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Foo', formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('-w','--url', help='URL', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-t','--test', help='Test command', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-m','--method', help='METHOD', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-u','--login_name', help='LOGIN', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-p','--login_password', help='PASSWORD', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-o','--output_format', help='OUTPUT', required=True, choices=['json', 'yaml', 'python'], default='json')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
```

*EDIT : After a lot of testing, I have managed the following :*

```
def testArgs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='DESCRIPTION')
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    p_list = subparsers.add_parser('test', help='List all available methods')
    p_list.add_argument('-w', help='URL', required=True)
    p_list.add_argument('-t', help='Test', action='store_true', required=True)
    p_cmd = subparsers.add_parser('cmd', help='Executes command')
    p_cmd.add_argument('-w', help='URL', required=True)
    p_cmd.add_argument('-m', help='Method', required=True)
    p_cmd.add_argument('-l', help='Login', required=True)
    p_cmd.add_argument('-p', help='Password', required=True)
    p_cmd.add_argument('-o', help='Output', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
```

Which exhibits the following behavior :

```
$ python testArgparse.py -h
usage: testArgeparse.py [-h] {test,cmd} ...

DESCRIPTION

positional arguments:
  {test,cmd}
    test      Lists all available methods
    cmd       Executes command

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

But to access help on the others arguments, I need to do the following :

```
$ python testArgparse.py test -h
usage: testArgparse.py test [-h] -w W -t

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -w W        URL
  -t          Test


$ python testArgparse.py cmd -h
usage: testArgparse.py cmd [-h] -w W -m M -l L -p P -o O

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -w W        URL
  -m M        Method
  -l L        Login
  -p P        Password
  -o O        Output
```

I'd like to be able to, at least, display help about all arguments without having to use `--help` for both `test` and `cmd` arguments.

Ideally, what I'd like is this behavior :

```
$ python testArgparse.py [-w URL -t] | [-w URL -m METHOD -u LOGIN -p PASS -o OUTPUT]
```

Comment: Just ignore the other arguments when you see ``-t/--test``

Comment: Added original code to first comment.

Comment: You should check out [mutually exclusive groups](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion).  You can make it so that one argument or the other is required, but not both.  You might have to do some trickery to have 1 *or* 3 groups, though.

Comment: So if '-t', the other arguments ('mupo') are no longer required.  You don't want to just ignore them.  Is that right?  For a start, I'd drop the 'required' flags, give them meaningful defaults, and test after `parse_args` for the presence or absence of necessary values.

Comment: Added the result from more testing on my side to original post.

Answer (score 1):

`required=True` with `store_true` does not make sense.  The default is `False`, but if it is required the returned value will always be `True`.

Since only `-w` is required unconditionally, I would drop the `required` parameter on everything else.  Then test for the required values after `parse_args`.  I can still issue an `argparse` error with usage at that time.  In other words, do my own testing rather than try something fancy in argparse.

```
def testArgs():
    usage = '[-w URL -t] | [-w URL -m METHOD -u LOGIN -p PASS -o OUTPUT]'
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='DESCRIPTION',usage=usage)
    parser.add_argument('-w', help='URL', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-t', help='Test', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-m', help='Method')
    parser.add_argument('-l', help='Login')
    parser.add_argument('-p', help='Password')
    parser.add_argument('-o', help='Output')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # sample test, streamline and refine to suit your needs
    # this assumes the default for all these args is None
    if not args.t: # '-t' in in argv
        if any([args.m is None, args.l is None, args.p is None, args.o is None]):
            parser.error('m,l,p,o are all required')
    return args

1216:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack21070971.py
usage: [-w URL -t] | [-w URL -m METHOD -u LOGIN -p PASS -o OUTPUT]
stack21070971.py: error: argument -w is required

1213:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack21070971.py -w url
usage: [-w URL -t] | [-w URL -m METHOD -u LOGIN -p PASS -o OUTPUT]
stack21070971.py: error: m,l,p,o are all required

1213:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack21070971.py -w url -t
Namespace(l=None, m=None, o=None, p=None, t=True, w='url')

1214:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack21070971.py -w url -m mmm
usage: [-w URL -t] | [-w URL -m METHOD -u LOGIN -p PASS -o OUTPUT]
stack21070971.py: error: m,l,p,o are all required
...

1215:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack21070971.py -w url -m mmm -l uuu -p ppp -o ooo
Namespace(l='uuu', m='mmm', o='ooo', p='ppp', t=False, w='url')
```

Comment: Thanks again, hpaulj.

I ended up using your suggestion and test the content of args.
I was told to stop using `sys.argv` to check for argument and use instead `argparse` but it seems there are still some cases where you have to work around the issue.